# Bar graph with large points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot a bar chart with 128 points with 2 in a group but the vertical bar overlap each other and representing in a square plot but i want in a rectangle plot, (where[image] the length of x-axis is larger than y-axis). The Minimal Working Environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = comma]{e2e_all.csv}\abletoe

 \begin{figure*}
 \centering
  %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},ylabel=Year,xtick={0,8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64}, enlarge x limits=true,legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1}, ybar interval=0.7]
 \addplot table [x=Core, y=v1, col sep=comma] {\abletoe} ;
 \addplot table [x=Core, y=carclip, col sep=comma] {\abletoe} ;
  \legend{Gaussian,Non-gaussian}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  %+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 \end{tabular}}
 \caption{xyz}
 \end{figure*}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Add `height=4cm,width=10cm` to both axis environments (or dimensions to your liking). You need to give both of these keys otherwise the default aspect ratio is preserved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is most likely solved in the comment below the question.

Comment: @percusse Can you make an answer from your comment?